# Wireless Internet not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and connected to the Internet through an Ethernet cable but am unable to even see WiFi options in the connection menu. Please help as I am a novice to Ubuntu and Linux. I have run a diagnostics test and the results are [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11996671/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have a solution for this (or enough points to just make a comment).
There is a [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940) about missing drivers for the Qualcomm chipset in your computer. Let me guess, Lenovo Yoga 3?

Comment: Its a Lenovo G50-80 but does this mean I can't connect to wifi until Ubuntu does something about it?

Comment: Yes (sort of). As a quick fix you could get a WiFi USB dongle with working drivers until the issue has been resolved. It may not be an issue only for Ubuntu however, it may take some time before brand new chipsets get Linux support.

Answer (score 0):

just connect the Ethernet cable (Broadband). open Additional Drivers option (you can search it on Ubuntu search) on Ubuntu 14.04 and search for the drivers there you can find missing drivers of your WiFi once you activate that restart the system. thank you i hope this will help you